# Validação de dados no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Olá, Tudo bem!?

Eu tô implementado uma regra de negocio na qual eu preciso validar dados, eu criei um repositorio externo a pasta http e tô usando a biblioteca [prettus/laravel-validation](https://github.com/andersao/laravel-validator) do composer para validar os dados com mais facilidade, pois bem o problema ocorre quando eu tento retornar os erros personalizado no qual o `metodo getMessage()` tá retornado uma mensagem vazia, enquanto o `getMessagebag()` retorna a mensagem padrão do `validator`. Eu queria saber como eu faço para retornar a mensagem de erro personalizada com este padrão que eu estou utilizando?

> Controller:

O controller não esta todo implementado ainda.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Sisten_site;
use App\Models\Data_users;
use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\UserService;




class UsersController extends Controller
{

    protected $service;

    public function __construct( UserService $service)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
    }


    public function create_user()
    {
        return view ("public_template.objects.new_user");  
    }

    public function save_user(Request $request)
    {

       $request= $this->service->store($request->all());
       $usuario=$request['message']; 


       dd($request);
   }

}
```

> User Service

```
    <?php

namespace App\Services;
use \Prettus\Validator\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;
use App \Validators\UserValidator;
use App\Models\Data_users;
use App\Models\Users;
use \Prettus\Validator\Exceptions\ValidatorException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;




class UserService
{


    protected $validator;

    public function __construct( UserValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator= $validator;
    }
    public function store($data)
    {
        try {


             $this->validator->with($data)->passesOrFail( ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE );

             $usuario= $this->salvando($data);

           return [

                'message'=>'Post created',
                'data'   => $usuario
            ];

        }catch (ValidatorException $e ) {


            return [
             'error'   =>false,
             'message' =>$e->getMessage()
            ];
        }        
    }
    public function salvando($data){

        $data_user=Data_users::Create($data);
            $user=Users::Create($data);
            $user->data_user()->associate($data_user);
            $user->save();
    }
}
```

> Classe para validação de dados.

```
<?php
namespace App\Validators;

use \Prettus\Validator\Contracts\ValidatorInterface;
use \Prettus\Validator\LaravelValidator;

class UserValidator extends LaravelValidator {

    protected $rules  = [
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
            'email_user' => 'required|unique:users,email_user',
        ],
        ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [

        ]
   ];

     protected  $retu = [*texto grifado*
    'email_user' => 'Este email já existe',
      ];

}
```

> DD

[image: Retorno de mensagem vazio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Laravel faz validações deste tipo de forme simples sem precisar de bibliotecas te terceiros. consulte a documentação do próprio Framework que está disponível aqui: [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation).

Comment: Ola @Everton bem vindo ao SOpt, nós sabemos que sua intenção é ajudar, porem da forma que sua resposta esta escrita ela se encaixa melhor como um comentário, tente melhora-la um pouco, Por exemplo: adicione um exemplo de como o ele pode aplicar essa validação. =P

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Icaro.